# PHP: how do I know the caller of a function?

Tags: php

how do I know the caller of a function in php ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: friend classes and ungreedy caller function/class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528671/php-friend-classes-and-ungreedy-caller-function-class) and [a couple others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=debug_backtrace+php). You should also read through [PHP debug_backtrace in production code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346703/php-debug-backtrace-in-production-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you would ever care about this, but you can figure that out from the [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) function.

Comment: It's fairly common in logging functions, rather than having to pass `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` etc.

Comment: Yes, and note that there is a moderate performance hit every time you call it.  Don't use it in production code...

Comment: Don't use it in production code *outside* of error logging functions.

Comment: @Charles I wouldnt use it *inside* error logging functions either. At least not each time. Not every error is so severe that it needs the backtrace. Use debug_backtrace when you need the backtrace to debug, but not to fiddle something like the caller from it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you want this, but let me raise a huge red flag - writing code whose behaviour depends on the caller generates very non-modular, hard to debug and downright crazy programs. That said, if you have a valid reason, something like...

```
function caller()
{
  $stackTrace = debug_backtrace();
  if (count ($stackTrace) < 1)
    return "None";
  else if (count ($stackTrace) < 2)
    return "Global scope " . $stackTrace[count($stackTrace)]["file"];
  else
    return $stackTrace[count($stackTrace) - 1]["function"];
}
```

(This was written off the cuff, so might not be robust in all situations. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php for more)

Answer (score 3):

> how do I know the caller of a function in php ?

Pass it into the callee. That's the most sane approach.

Comment: Do you mean with `(this)` or something of the sort?

Comment: @typoking with `$this`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__CLASS__`, whatever you need in the callee - just dont do it with `debug_backtrace` unless you need the backtrace.