# Find the class name of the calling function in php

Tags: php, static-methods

Lets say I have:

```
    class Zebra{
        public static function action(){
            print 'I was called from the '.get_class().' class'; // How do I get water here?
        }
    }

    class Water{
        public static function drink(){
            Zebra::action();
        }
    }

Water::drink();
```

How do I get "water" from the zebra class?

(This is for php 5.3)

Comment: Look into `debug_backtrace`. But you really don't want to be doing that in normal code paths.

Comment: Try to do get_called_class() instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: how do I know the caller of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330938/php-how-do-i-know-the-caller-of-a-function)

Comment: @Matt that would still be Zebra because this is not an issue of LSB. The OP does call Zebra.

Comment: If you need to make decisions based on the Caller, you might want to rethink your design. You should not have that need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One not so good solution is :
use `__METHOD__` or `__FUNCTION__` or `__CLASS__` .
and pass it as parameter to function being called.
http://codepad.org/AVG0Taq7

```
<?php

  class Zebra{
        public static function action($source){
            print 'I was called from the '.$source.' class'; // How do I get water here?
        }
    }

    class Water{
        public static function drink(){
            Zebra::action(__CLASS__);
        }
    }

Water::drink();

?>
```

Comment: that's not the "not so good solution" but the only sane solution.

Comment: @gordon , I find it not so good, because he will have to edit an existing code for that. A better solution would have been which could have made this possible without code modification. I am not sure if there exists any.

Comment: Thanks, this is how I had it originally, its what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Dhruv that "other" solution would involve debug_backtrace which is bad practise. If the OP needs the information inside that function it should be an argument passed into the function. Anything else breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the caller's info from `debug_backtrace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Not too keen on using back trace either. - there might not be a solution

Comment: *(related)* [`debug_backtrace` in production code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346703/php-debug-backtrace-in-production-code)

Answer (score 1):

Full usable solution using exception, but not debug_backtrace, no need to modify any prototype :

```
function getRealCallClass($functionName)
{
  try
   {
     throw new exception();
   }
  catch(exception $e)
   {
     $trace = $e->getTrace();
     $bInfunction = false;
     foreach($trace as $trace_piece)
      {
          if ($trace_piece['function'] == $functionName)
           {
             if (!$bInfunction)
              $bInfunction = true;
           }
          elseif($bInfunction) //found !!!
           {
             return $trace_piece['class'];
           }
      }
   }
}

class Zebra{
        public static function action(){
        print 'I was called from the '.getRealCallClass(__FUNCTION__).' class'; 
    }
}

class Water{
    public static function drink(){
        Zebra::action();
    }
}

Water::drink();
```